# How to get a webserver's content from a local html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So right now I have a html file which I need locally stored, when I open this webpage I need it to download some content from a webserver.

I've tried using Jquery's AJAX but that doesnt let me use cross domain, so I am stuck, here is what I have tried to get to work

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var url = 'example.com/function.php?ID=' + id;
        $( "#result" ).load( url);
    });
</script>
```

Obviously Im aware the above code I made does not work as it has something to do with it being cross domain.

Comment: example.com has to allow the cross-domain usage.

Comment: Its not that simple due to [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSONp method, this method is **preferable**. Here is how: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3506306/5434216)

Or you can allow access on server side by using `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` in php headers. You write your own domain instead of using `*`